# ClassCastException: ApiException cannot be cast to RevolvableApiException after updating location library to 21 version

Tags: android, location

I have updated location services libraries in my App to the latest 21 version:
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0` 
and it breaks the logic for enabling location settings on the users phones.

I found updated page with documentation about this process:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient, 
and using code below for triggering popup which should ask user to allow enabling location access on the phone:

```
val locationRequest = LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 10000)
                .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(5000).build()

            val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)

            val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity)
            val task: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
            task.addOnCompleteListener {
                try {
                    task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                } catch (exception: ApiException) {
                    when (exception.statusCode) {
                        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                            try {
                                val resolvable = exception as ResolvableApiException
                                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                    activity,
                                    1
                                )
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

but that code from documentation throw a ClassCastException on this line: 
`val resolvable = exception as ResolvableApiException`, 
can't figure out how to deal with a latest location updates, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error:** Exception e is instantiated as "ApiException" so casting to ResolveApiException(subclass) is not possible.

```
e.getClass();//returnsString ApiException instead of ResolveApiException
```

**A possible workaround**:use ResolvableApiException constructor,requires only status code.

```
ResolvableApiException resolvable = new ResolvableApiException(exception.getStatus());
//use ResolvableApiException Constructor
//public ResolvableApiException (Status status)
```

Comment: it worked for me too. I used a Samsung Galaxy S8 using Android 9. Thanks

Comment: Is this actually a breaking change in 21:0:0 ?

Comment: From play service Setting Client docs:If the status code is CommonStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, the client can call ResolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(Activity, int) . Probably some mistake in docs . [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient#checkLocationSettings(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest))

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Gui_user for the solution.

In kotlin you can do like this on the fly instead of doing a cast to `ResolvableApiException`:

```
ResolvableApiException(exception.status).startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved in play-services-location **21.0.1**. Exception is now a ResolvableApiException.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_03_2022

Comment: It doesn't seen to be resolved in my application... It keeps occuring. Are you sure it was resolved?